# How build to deploy node app to http server

Tags: node.js, apache, http, deployment, production

Is there any way to use express or other **nodejs** librarys to to design an api and deploy it pasting files as a resource path in a **web server** just like react.

My web server just listen on ports 80 and 443.
I have pages on domain.com/page1 domain.com/page2.
and i want to deploy an api listening on domain.com/page3 but i cant install a nodejs server and proxy requests to page3 to it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your existing web server that listens on ports 80 and 443?  Is it a nodejs-based server?

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one web server listening on a given port.  You can directly "listen to a path", only a port.

So, if you already have an existing web server running on ports 80 and 443, then these are your options.

1. **Modify your existing web server to add your API server code** to it so it can handle requests for `http://yourdomain.com/page3` and `https://yourdomain.com/page3` directly with your API.
2. **You can add some middleware to your existing web server to make it a proxy** for `http://yourdomain.com/page3` that will redirect requests to your `http://yourdomain.com:3000/page3` Express-based API server.
3. **Run your own Express-based API server on your own separate port and access the API server directly via the separate port** such as `http://yourdomain.com:3000/page3`.
4. **You can install a proxy such as nginx in front of your existing web server and have it redirect incoming requests** to `http://yourdomain.com/page3` and `https://yourdomain.com/page3` to the separate port that your Express-based API server is running on.